# Tomcat was killed by kernel

Tags: java, linux, embedded-tomcat-7

My tomcat was auto-shutdown suddenly.I checked in log file and found that It was killed with message:

`kernel: Killed process 17420, UID 0, (java) total-vm:8695172kB, anon-rss:4389088kB, file-rss:20kB`

My setting for running tomcat is `-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`

My system when run command "free -m" is:

```
     total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem: 7859 7713 146 0 97 1600 
-/+ buffers/cache: 6015 1844 Swap: 0 0 0
```

I monitor program with "top -p", the result as below

```
Cpu(s): 0.1%us, 0.0%sy, 0.0%ni, 99.9%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 0.0%st Mem: 8048440k total, 7900616k used, 147824k free, 100208k buffers Swap: 0k total, 0k used, 0k free, 1640888k cached

PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
4473 root 20 0 8670m 2.5g 6568 S 0.0 32.6 71:07.84 java
```

My question is:

1.Why VIRT = 8670m (in "top -p" result) is greater than Mem: 8048440k total but my application is still running?

2. Why my tomcat was kill by kernel? I don't see any strange with memory (It's similar with when it's running)
3. To avoid this error happen, what will I do and why?

Comment: You'll likely get a wider audience on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I know that causes the kernel to kill tasks in Linux is the [out of memory killer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html). [This article from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html) might be a little more recently and relevant.

The solution depends on what else is running on the system. From what you showed, you have less than 2GB of usable memory, but your Java heap max is topping out around 4GB. What we don't know is how big the Java heap is at the time you took that snapshot. If it's at its initial 2GB, then you could be running close to the limit. Also based on your formatting, you have no swap space to use as a fallback.

If you have any other significant processes on the system, you need to account for their maximum memory usage. The short answer is try to reduce the Xmx and MaxPermSize if at all possible, you'll have to analyze your load to see if this is possible or will cause unreasonable GC CPU usage.

Some notes:

1. Java uses more memory than the heap, it has memory for the native code running the VM itself.
2. Java 8 stores permgen outside of the heap, so I believe it adds memory on top of the Xmx parameter, you may want to note that if running Java 8.
3. As you reduce the memory limit, you'll hit 3 ranges:

   1. Far above real requirements: no noticeable difference
   2. Very close to real requirements: server freezes/stops responding and uses 100% CPU (GC overhead)
   3. Below real requirements: OutOfMemoryErrors
4. It's possible for a process's VM size to exceed RAM+swap size per your first question. I remember running Java on a swapless embedded system with 256MB RAM and seeing 500MB of memory usage and being surprised. Some reasons:

   1. In Linux you can allocate memory, but it's not actually used until you write to it
   2. Memory-mapped files (and probably things like shared memory segments) count towards this limit. I believe Java opens all of the jar files as memory mapped files so included in that virt size are all of the jars on your classpath, including the 80MB or so rt.jar.
   3. Shared objects probably count towards VIRT but only occupy space once (i.e. one copy of so loaded for many processes)
   4. I've heard, but I can't find a reference right now, that Linux can actually use binaries/.so files as read-only "swap" space, meaning essentially loading a 2MB binary/so will increase your VM size by 2MB but not actually use all of that RAM, because it pages in from disk only the parts actually accessed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Linux OS has a OOM Mechanism, when OS's memory is insufficient. The OOM will kill the cost max memory program(In most situations, [Linux Out Of Memory Management](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html)). Obviously Your tomcat own the max memory.
2. How to solve? In my experience, you must observe the memory usage of OS, you can use the top command to observe, and find the proper process. and at the same time, you can use the jvisualvm to observe the usage memory of tomcat.

Comment: OOM killer won't just kill largest process (although normally it's the case). It favors long-running processes even if large. If OOM is killing real processes, you're in the crapper anyway and need more RAM/swap. The point of the OOM is to stop runaway short-term processes that get stuck in an infinite loop eating RAM. That's why OOM killer kills short-lived processes using lots of RAM first.